# Not using an element in a list once randomly chosen

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this program that randomly chooses some characters, like this:

```
things = ("doge", "cat", "actual dog", "rabbit")
for i in range(20):
    print random.randint(1, len(things))-1
```

I want `doge` to not be selected again. once randomly selected from the list `things`. How can I do this? Please give a method that can work in a variety of situations. Thanks!

Comment: This will print only integers, not elements from the list.

Comment: The easiest way would be to simply remove it from the list. Or you could keep track without mutating the list by having a temp list storing used values, and `if i == temp_i: pass` edit: there is an easier way.

Comment: How do you plan to make 20 random choices from a four-element list?! Also, `random.randrange(len(things))` is much neater.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Some of the choices will be repeated, but one will be repeated only once.

Comment: @SomeGuy huh? *Some of the choices will be repeated, but one will be repeated only once* - could you give an example?

Comment: @JonClements Lets say I choose a random char 5 times. `Doge` can only be selected once. `cat actual_dog doge cat actual_dog`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `random.sample`. For example:

```
import random
x = range(10)
y = random.sample(x, 4) # Pick 4 distinct elements from x
```

Comment: @RUJordan: The `random` module contains a lot of functionality for common cases (e.g. `random.shuffle` to randomly mix a list). See https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: @6502 my first thought I don't *really* understand the question, the second is that I'd probably just build a `list` from `things` and `random.shuffle` it each time. For a one time run, I imagine sample to win, for multiple runs, I'd take a guess that shuffle (being in-place and not creating new lists) would be better.

Comment: @JonClements: using `random.sample` the elements are chosen before the loop, i.e. you just do `for element in random.sample(L, n): ...`. If instead you don't know how many elements you're going to use you can use `random.shuffle` on a copy of the list and stop when you like. The problem is more complex if instead the list is changing during the iteration...